# WIX finds registry path but doesn't satisfy condition

Tags: wix

My WIX-based installer is trying to verify an existing registry key.  Then satisfy a condition to continue installing.  Although "MS Project" exists, my condition fails.

```
<Property Id="MSPROJECT2013">
<RegistrySearch Id="MSProject2013"
Root="HKCU"
Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\MS Project"
Name="ProjectName"
Type="raw" />
</Property>

<Condition Message="This application requires MS Project 2010 or 2013.">
<![CDATA[Installed OR MSPROJECT2013]]>
</Condition>
```

The relevant verbose output:

```
Action 16:59:35: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
Action start 16:59:35: AppSearch.
AppSearch: Property: MSPROJECT2013, Signature: MSProject2013
MSI (c) (14:00) [16:59:35:547]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
Action ended 16:59:35: AppSearch. Return value 1.

This application requires MS Project 2010 or 2013.
MSI (c) (14:00) [16:59:36:582]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (14:00) [16:59:36:582]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (c) (14:00) [16:59:36:582]: Product: reporting -- This application requires MS Project 2010 or 2013.
```

I thought it was a permissions issue but the registry permissions are fine.  I tried other locations but it's still failing.  I can't find the ProductID or UpgradeCode in the Registry (as a failed uninstall/install) either!  I also ran the Microsoft Fixit that replaced their install cleanup tool.  What could be the issue?

Comment: If it's a 32-bit MSI and that item is in the 64-bit registry it won't find it.

Comment: Unfortunately the system is 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

The RegistrySearch failed; if it had succeeded, the log would have included a line reporting the value that was found in the new property value.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Such as a successful log entry?  The odd thing is, the path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\MS Project` exists!  Would `Name=ProjectName` have anything to do with it?

Comment: The Name attribute identifies the name of the value to be read. Does that value exist?